# Format data from store before binding

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have a store with data like this:

name: "black", color: "RGB: 0, 0, 0"

Now I want to create a grid that shows the data with an extra column that shows a thumbnail of the color. Basically just a small square with a background color. I know there is tpl and renderer but the documentation advises using bind. So how can I transform a field from the store with bind? There's Ext.util.Format and I can make it work by combining several formatters but it would be much cleaner if I could use my own function.

Comment: Please provide at least some code you already user or even better provide a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you have to do is to generate a color value in an format accepted by css. For this you can use the [`calculate`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-calculate) method of [`Ext.data.field.Field`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html). There are many other ways to do this.

```
Ext.define('Color', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'color',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'displayColor',
        type: 'string',
        calculate: function (data) {

            var color = data.color;
            //parse your value to CSS Colors here
            return '#FF0000';
        }
    }]
});
```

To display the background color in the column, I would create a new column widget. This would take care of drawing the cell.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.BackgroundVisualize', {
    extend: 'Ext.Gadget',
    xtype: ['myBackgroundwidget'],

    template: [{
        reference: 'backgroundEl'
    }],

    defaultBindProperty: 'value',

    setValue: function (value, oldValue) {
        this.el.up('td').setStyle('background', value);
    }
});
```

This new widget must then only be used as a column in the grid.

```
{
    text: 'Preview',
    xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
    widget: {
        xtype: 'myBackgroundwidget',
        bind: '{record.displayColor}'
    }
}
```

Here is the complete example:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22ln

Comment: IMO, because the value is a display value, it doesn't belong as a calculated field on the model, rather it should be a concern of the UI. Also, a widget column is probably overkill just for that.

Comment: I ended up storing the color in the store as hex. Then I used convert to display it as RGB in a column and used a widget column to display the thumb. I decided to use a widget because I had to use a color thumb in a few different places as well.

Also note that `bind: '{record.displayColor}'` only works for 6.2 and up. For 6.0 I had to use dataIndex.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate version based off an existing answer. It's a simpler version that uses a column renderer to display the value. A widget column may be a bit heavy for this use. YMMV, depending on what your needs are.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        new Ext.grid.Panel({
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            store: {
                data: [{
                    name: 'red',
                    color: 'RGB: 255, 0, 0'
                }]
            },
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }, {
                text: 'Color',
                dataIndex: 'color',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Preview',
                renderer: function (v, meta, rec) {
                    var color = rec.get('color');
                    // Parse model value into displayable color
                    return '<div style="width: 100%; height: 1em; background-color: #FF0000;"></div>';
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22lt)